# If $\partial\Omega\in C^{2+\alpha}$ and $-\Delta\Theta=f\text{ in }\Omega$ with $f\in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$, then $\Theta\in C^{2+\alpha}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let

- $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain with $\partial\Omega\in C^{2+\alpha}$ for some $\alpha>0$
- $f\in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$
- $\Theta\in C^0(\overline{\Omega})\cap C^2(\Omega)$ be the solution of $$-\Delta\left.\Theta\right|_{\Omega}\equiv f\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;\left.\Theta\right|_{\partial\Omega}\equiv 0$$

Why can we assume $\Theta\in C^{2+\alpha}(\overline{\Omega})$? I've read that this is due to $\partial\Omega\in C^{2+\alpha}$, but I don't understand why.

---

*Please note*:$\;\;\;$ I'm unsure if I even really understood what is meant by $C^{2+\alpha}$. I assume that $C^{2+\alpha}$ is the space of all $C^2$-functions that are $\alpha$-Hölder continuous, but I may be wrong and someone who is more familiar with this context might be able to correct me.

Comment: Deleted my previous comment because ultimately I was directing you towards some results on a Sobolev space, which is not what you asked.  Anyway this is an example of an elliptic regularity theorem.  I don't have a happy answer for you - regularity is very important but I do not know of a good comprehensive treatment.  In my opinion the proofs of these results are always a bit unpleasant.

Comment: This comes from the Schauder estimates of PDEs. It's one of the best classical results of elliptic PDE theory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_estimates

Comment: Maybe this will help you with the definition of 
$C^{2+\alpha}$. 
[Does anybody know the definition][1]


  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1390812/does-anybody-know-the-definition-of-c2-alpha-1-frac-alpha2-omega