# Does anybody know the definition of $C^{2+\alpha, 1+\frac{\alpha}{2}}(\Omega)$, where $0<\alpha<1$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, definition

I hope someone can give me the definition of the following:

> $C^{2+\alpha, 1+\frac{\alpha}{2}}(\Omega)$ for some $0<\alpha<1$ and some domain $\Omega$.

In this context they also talk about $\Omega$ as a bounded and $C^{2+\alpha}$ domain. What does this mean? . (bounded is clear ;) )

I found this in a paper about non-local diffusion.
(It is used in many theorems, but there is no definition...)

Does this rooms have an specific name? Sorry if this something I should know, but if you don't know the name if this it is really hard to find with Google ore something else ;).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$C^{2,1}(\Omega)$ usually refer to the set of function that are $C^2$ on $\Omega$ with respect to the first variable, and $C^1$ with respect to the second one.

In case you have "fractional" numbers, it usually refers to the  Holder condition as mentioned in the other answer.

We say that a certain domain (open and convex) $\Omega$ is $C^2$ if some specific conditions are met[0]; basically it tells you that locally, the boundary of $\Omega$ can be represented by the graph of a certain $C^2$ function

[0]

**Formal definition**

> We say that $\Omega$ is a $C^1$ domain if for every $x \in \partial
>  \Omega$, there exists a coordinate system $(y_1, \dots, y_n) \equiv
>  (\bar y', y_n)$ with origin in $x$, a sphere $B(x)$ and a function
>   $\varphi$, defined in a neighborhood $\mathcal N \subset \mathbb
>  R^{n-1}$ of $\bar y' = 0$, such that
>
> $$\varphi \in C^1(\mathcal N), \varphi(0) = 0$$ $$\partial \Omega \cap
>  B(x) = \{(\bar y', y_n): y_n = \varphi(\bar y'), \bar  y' \in \mathcal
>  N\}$$ $$\Omega \cap B(x) = \{(\bar y', y_n): y_n > \varphi(\bar y'),
>  \bar  y' \in \mathcal N\}$$

The second condition reflects the fact that $\partial \Omega$ is locally the graph of a $C^1$ function, and the third that $\Omega$ is locally on the same side with respect to $\partial \Omega$.

If you want a $C^2$ domain or a Lipschitz domain replace the above $C^1$ with the corresponding space of functions ;-)

P.S. Definition taken from "Partial differential equation" by Salsa

Comment: Thanks a lot. This should be the right definition.

Comment: @Mathnix I just added the formal definition for $C^1$ domain as I did not find it on wikipedia ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I did know this definition in the case we have natural numbers in the exponent. I only was confused about the real number we have now.

But with you definition it is clear know.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be a [Hölder condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition).

Comment: Thank you. This should be right.

Comment: I’ve found this question and I think that I’m reading the same nonlocal difusion problem paper, with the same doubt. I think that can not be hölder condiction because the definition in your link said that $1+\alpha/2$ implies the function is constant. Am I see something wrong? Looking the above answer, I think that is $2+\alpha$ with $0<\alpha<1$ but I don`t understand this index and your continuity class. I really want to understand this better.

Comment: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s11856-009-0019-8.pdf page 3